# Display Mysql Tbl Results With Pagination

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

I need to do things in procedural style using mysqli. Have not learnt oop style or pdo yet.

I am trying to create a pagination page where 10 pages display all records. Records spread over 10 pages.
Even though my tbl has records, I get notice that no records exist. No records are being displayed in the html table.
Why is that ?

Following is my attempt to show records using PREP STMT procedural style using mysqli.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional/EN"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  http-equiv="content-type"> 
<title><?php echo "$site_name $user"; ?> User's Notices in <?php echo 
$server_time; ?> time.</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<br> 
<center><span style="font-weight: bold;"><?php echo "$site_name $user"; ?> 
User's Notices in <?php echo $server_time; ?> time.</span></center> 
<br> 
<br> 
<?php 
$query = "SELECT id,date_and_time,recipient_username,sender_username,notice 
FROM notices WHERE recipient_username = ?"; 

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,$query)) 
{     
    //Bind Parameter 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$recipient_username);  
    //Execute Statement 
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    //$result_1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query); 
    //Bind Result Variables     
    $result_1 = mysqli_stmt_bind_result
    ($stmt,$id,$date_and_time,
    $recipient_username,$sender_username,$notice); 
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt); 
    $rows_num = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);    
    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rows_num); 

    $page_count = 10; 
    $page_size = ceil($rows_num / $page_count); 
    //Get the Page Number, Default is 1 (First Page).   
    $page_number = $_GET["page_number"]; 
    if ($page_number == "") $page_number = 1; 
    $offset = ($page_number -1) * $page_size; 

    $query .= " limit {$offset},{$page_size}";      

?>  
<table width="1500" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" 
bgcolor="#666666"> 
<?php if($rows_num) {?> 
<tr name="headings"> 
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="column-heading_submission-number">Submission 
Number</td> 
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="column-heading_logging-server-date-&-time">Date 
& Time in <?php echo $server_time ?></td> 
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="column-heading_to">To</td> 
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="column-heading_from">From</td> 
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="column-heading_notice">Notice</td> 
</tr>   
<?php while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) 
{ 
    ?> 
    <tr name="user-details"> 
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="submission-number"><?php echo $row['id']; ?>
</td> 
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="logging-server-date-&-time"><?php echo 
$row['date_and_time']; ?></td> 
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="recipient_username"><?php echo 
$row['recipient_username']; ?></td> 
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="sender_username"><?php echo 
$row['sender_username']; ?></td> 
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="notice"><?php echo $row['notice']; ?></td>  
    </tr> 
    <?php 
} 
?> 
<tr name="pagination"> 
<td colspan="10" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> Result Pages: 
<?php 
$rows_num = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt); 
if($rows_num <= $page_size) 
{ 
    echo "Page 1"; 
} 
else 
{ 
    for($i=1;$i<=$page_count;$i++) 
    echo "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page_number={$i}\">{$i}</a>  "; 
} 
?> 
</td> 
</tr> 
<?php 
} 
else 
{ 
    ?> 
    <tr> 
    <td bgcolor="FFFFFF">No record found! Try another time.</td> 
    </tr> 
    <?php 
} 
?> 
</table> 
<br> 
<br> 
<center><span style="font-weight: bold;"><?php echo "$site_name $user"; ?> 
User's Notices in <?php echo $server_time; ?> time.</span></center> 
<br> 
<br> 
</div> 
<br> 
</body> 
</html> 
<?php 
} 
//Free Result Set 
mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt); 

//Close Database Connection 
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 

?>
```

I get echoed:

Result set has 0 rows.
No record found! Try another time.

This is false. There are records in the mysql tbl.

Ignore the outdated htmls as I will upgrade them to html 5 later. At the moment, I'm in a fix with php.

Comment: You could have definitely made a much more simpler example, instead of just dumping your whole code here

Comment: If I don't dump my whole code here then you experts will be in the dark to what is causing the malfunction as I am totally puzzled about this whole affair.

Comment: You of course need to replicate the issue with as short code as possible -- and that's the way you also figure out where the problem actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I use for my pagination.  It's a bit more flexible too that just fixing it to 10 pages.

```
// Get inital params
if (isset($_GET['page'])) { $page = $_GET['page']; } else { $page = 1; }
$max_results = 100;
$offset = $page*$max_results - $max_results;
// This is the maximium amount of pages to display before adding Prev \ Next
$max = 10;

$query = "SELECT id FROM notices WHERE recipient_username = ?";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,$query)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$recipient_username);  
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt); 
    $records = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
function get_paging_info($count, $offset, $curr_page)
{
    $pages = ceil($count / $offset);

    $data = array();
    $data['si']        = ($curr_page * $offset) - $offset;
    $data['pages']     = $pages;
    $data['curr_page'] = $curr_page;

    return $data; //return the paging data

}

$paging_info = get_paging_info($records, $max_results, $page);

$html = "";

if($paging_info['curr_page'] > 1) {

        $html = $html . "<a href='1' title='Page 1'>First</a> <a href='" . ($paging_info['curr_page'] - 1) . "' title='Page " . ($paging_info['curr_page'] - 1) . "'>Prev</a>";

}

if($paging_info['curr_page'] < $max) {
    $sp = 1;
} else {
    if($paging_info['curr_page'] >= ($paging_info['pages'] - floor($max / 2)) ) {
        $sp = $paging_info['pages'] - $max + 1;
    } else {
        if($paging_info['curr_page'] >= $max) {
            $sp = $paging_info['curr_page']  - floor($max/2);
        }
    }
}

if($paging_info['curr_page'] >= $max) {
    $html = $html . "<a href='1' title='Page 1'> 1</a> ... ";
}

for($i = $sp; $i <= ($sp + $max -1);$i++) {
    if($i > $paging_info['pages']) { continue; }

    if($paging_info['curr_page'] == $i) {
        $html = $html . "<span class='bold'> {$i}</span>";
    } else {
        $html = $html . "<a href='{$i}' title='Page {$i}'> {$i}</a>";
    }
}

if($paging_info['curr_page'] < ($paging_info['pages'] - floor($max / 2)) && ($paging_info['pages'] > ($sp + $max -1))) {
    $html = $html . " ... <a href='{$paging_info['pages']}' title='Page {$paging_info['pages']}'>{$paging_info['pages']}</a>";
}
if($paging_info['curr_page'] < $paging_info['pages']) {
    $html = $html . " <a href='" . ($paging_info['curr_page'] + 1) . "' title='Page " . ($paging_info['curr_page'] + 1) . "'>Next</a><a href='{$paging_info['pages']}' title='Page {$paging_info['pages']}'> Last</a>";
}
```

Then for the code to go through the database:

```
<table width="1500" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" 
bgcolor="#666666"> 
<?php if($records) {?> 
<tr name="headings"> 
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="column-heading_submission-number">Submission 
Number</td> 
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="column-heading_logging-server-date-&-time">Date 
& Time in <?php echo $server_time ?></td> 
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="column-heading_to">To</td> 
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="column-heading_from">From</td> 
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="column-heading_notice">Notice</td> 
</tr>   

<?php
$query = "SELECT id,date_and_time,recipient_username,sender_username,notice 
FROM notices WHERE recipient_username = ? LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,$query)) 
{     
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'sii',$recipient_username, $max_results, $offset);  
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$id,$date_and_time,$recipient_username,$sender_username,$notice); 
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt); 
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
    ?>
        <tr name="user-details"> 
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="submission-number"><?php echo $id; ?></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="logging-server-date-&-time"><?php echo $date_and_time; ?></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="recipient_username"><?php echo $recipient_username; ?></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="sender_username"><?php echo $sender_username; ?></td> 
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="notice"><?php echo $notice; ?></td>  
        </tr> 
    <?php 
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
?>

<tr name="pagination"><td colspan="10" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $html; ?></td></tr>
```

Note:  You'll obviously have to edit the links to w\e you need them to be.  This script will let you set the max page length dynamically rather than fixing it at 10 which could cause problems down the road.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hard work. Most appreciated.
However, I'm a beginner and still learning procedural style using mysqli. Will migrate to pdo and oop style. I guess your code is in oop style. I can copy & paste your code and I'm sure it will work but I will not progress much in my learning due to failing to understand the oop style. Therefore, any chance you can convert this to procedural style after this comment by retaining the oop style above ? That way, I can learn from the oop style version after I migrate to pdo.

Comment: Currently, most of my pages I built for this project is procedural style and so can't just jump to oop style in the middle of things. I'll get confused.
I hope I'm not asking for too much. Afterall, I need to learn from you seniors and not just copy & paste without fully understanding what I'm copying. I hope you understand.

Comment: Alright that should be more or less correct, I tried to clean up some of your superfluous code and didn't have time to fully test it so there might be some minor issues, just a warning in advance, but you should be able to understand the gist of it from that update

Comment: Thanks mason. But what exactly should I put on:
// Your Code
I thought you gave me the full code.
Anyway, I see you have created 2 blocks of code. So, on my page, I first insert the 1st block and then underneath it the 2nd ? It did not work on my side doing it like that. What am I missing ?

Comment: "Your code" is all the HTML \ display stuff you have in there that I didn't want to paste in the answer.  The top part generates a dynamic count of pages and adds First Prev \ Next Last if the list gets longer than the variable $max automatically.  I also changed the SQL query to handle your offset \ limit in the SQL query itself.

Comment: IE the top part generates First Prev 1 ... 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 ... 249 Next Last

Comment: I did add my html where you commented "Your code here" but still see tonnes of errors. Getting confused now.
I'm having problem putting both blocks of codes together correctly integrating with my html without seeing errors and so do you mind putting them together and pasting them here so I can copy & paste it on my xampp and see how it's functioning and then go line by line on each line of your code to learn how you coded it ?


Thanks!

Comment: Updated with your html.

Comment: Thanks Mason. Tested your edit now. I got a few errors. Undefined variable: num_rows in line ...: <?php if($num_rows) {?> . I switched the var to $stmt and error gone. 
Also, I got undefined $sql error at 2 places and so switched them to $query and working. Do you mind fixing this on your update above so others trying-out your code do not experience these same problems (typos). 
And, I get displayed only the final row out of 6 matching rows/records I have in the mysql tbl. Why is that ? The query is supposed to pull all rows/records.
Once again: Thank you very much!

Comment: Updated the syntax changes I missed.  Check the offset \ Limit variables and see what they're resolving to.  They're meant to interact with the page number to limit the SQL query results.

Comment: I've lost the copy you gave me (procedural style pagination with search capability). Do you mind attaching the file here again ?
Best to copy & paste the whole code here for other newbie's benefits.

Thanbks!